# $n_{i+1} = \lceil n_i/2 \rceil + 1$, get a TIGHT upper bound of sum $\sum_{i=0}^d \lfloor n_i/2 \rfloor$

Tags: inequality, summation, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For any $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, define a sequence $\{n_i\}$:
$$
\begin{cases}
n_0=n\\
n_{i+1}=\lceil n_i/2 \rceil + 1
\end{cases}
$$
and $\{k_i\}$ are the terms to be added:
$$ k_i = \lfloor n_i/2 \rfloor $$
$d$ is the length of the summation, $d \le \log_2{n}$.

I have worked out the following result:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} k_i \le (1-{1 \over 2^d})n+c_1d+c_2
$$
here $c_1,c_2$ are constants, and $c_1 \le 1.5$ .

But what I really want is to prove $c_1 \le 1$, and I believe it's true (by numeric tests).

Could anyone help me?

**My Work**
$$
n_{i+1} \le {n_i +1 \over 2} + 1 = {n_i + 3 \over 2} \\
n_1 \le {n_0 + 3 \over 2} = {n \over 2} + {3 \over 2} \\
n_2 \le {n_1 + 3 \over 2} \le {n \over 4} + {3 \over 2} + {3 \over 4}\\
\vdots\\
n_i \le {n \over 2^i} + {3 \over 2} + {3 \over 4} + {3 \over 8} + \cdots + {3 \over 2^i}\\
n_i \le {n \over 2^i} + 3\\
k_i \le {n_i \over 2} \le {n \over 2^{i+1}} + 1.5\\
\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} k_i \le (1-{1 \over 2^d})n+1.5d
$$

**Background**

I am trying to analyse the time complexity of Schönhage–Strassen algorithm, using recursion tree method.
Assume input size $N = 2^n$:
if $c_1 \le 1.5$, then $T(N)=O(N\log^{1.5}{N})$;
if $c_1 \le 1$ proved, then $T(N)=O(N\log{N}\log\log{N})$ proved.

Answer (score 1):

By induction we can easily show that $n_i\ge \frac {n-1}{2^i}+1$. Also for each $i$ we have $k_i=n_i-n_{i+1}+1$. Thus

$$\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} k_i=\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} n_i-n_{i+1}+1=n+d-n_d\le (n-1)(1-2^{-d})+d.$$